# How to trigger a function when side menu opens | Ionic React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner in Ionic React
How can I trigger an event when side menu opens in Ionic React ?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#events

I've read this but don't know how to implement this.

I tried implementing like this but it didn't worked out.

```
<IonMenu ionDidOpen={myFunc} ....
```

Comment: more code would be helpful

Comment: Try Like: `<IonMenu ionDidOpen={()=>{YourFunction()}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I actually got the solution.

This worked out for me -
`<IonMenu onIonDidOpen={myFunc} ....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.

```
 useEffect(() => { console.log('hello') })
```